# The following python code giving an inappropriate output

Tags: python

This is the question-Write a python program that reads three angles of a triangle from the user and prints "Isosceles Right Triangle" if the input angles contain 45,45 and 90 degrees(Order does not matter), "Equilateral Triangle" if all the angles are equal, "Isosceles Triangle" if two angles are equal and "Scalene Triangle" if there are no equal angles. Remember: All triangles add up to 180 degrees and all angles must be greater than 0 degrees so print "Not A Triangle" if this rule is broken. Assume user always inputs interger angles.
And this is my code-

```
x=int(input('Enter 1st angle: '))
y=int(input('Enter 2nd angle: '))
z=int(input('Enter 3rd angle: '))
sum=int(x+y+z)
if(sum!=180 or x<=0 or y<=0 or z<=0):
    print('Not a Triangle')
if((x==45 and y==45 and z==90) or (x==45 and y==90 and z==45) or (x==90 and y==45 and z==45)):
    print('Isosceles Right Triangle')
if((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and (x==y or y==z or z==x)):
    print('Isosceles Triangle')
if((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and ((x==y and z==x) or (x==z and y==z) or(x==y and z==y))):
    print('Equilateral Triangle')
if((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and (x!=y and x!=z and z!=y)):
    print('Scalene Triangle')
```

Here my problem is when I am giving the input 0,0,180 the output should be only Not a triangle, but I am having output as 'Not a triangle' and 'Isosceles triangle'.

Comment: `y!=0 or z!=0` should read `y!=0 and z!=0` in your isosceles condition. You could also use an else clause to your first if, or have an early exit if the values don't define a triangle

Comment: A little trick to reduce the number of checks is to put x, y, z into a list and sort them. i.e `angles = sorted([x, y, z])`

Comment: You need to use ```if....elif....elif....else```. Your ```if....if...if``` are separate blocks, each of which will be executed, unlike ```if...elif...else```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining Isosceles Triangle as two angles being equal. Since two angles in the example are equal to zero, it will also be considered an Isosceles triangle.

I would do if elif statements instead.

```
if(sum!=180 or x<=0 or y<=0 or z<=0):
    print('Not a Triangle')
elif((x==45 and y==45 and z==90) or (x==45 and y==90 and z==45) or (x==90 and y==45 and z==45)):
    print('Isosceles Right Triangle')
elif((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 and z!=0) and (x==y or y==z or z==x)):
    print('Isosceles Triangle')
elif((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and ((x==y and z==x) or (x==z and y==z) or(x==y and z==y))):
    print('Equilateral Triangle')
elif((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and (x!=y and x!=z and z!=y)):
    print('Scalene Triangle') 
else:
   print('Not a Triangle')
```

This will make the options mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You are going a lot of unnecessary checks.

```
if sum != 180:
    print("Not a triangle: angles do not sum to 180")
# From now on, assume sum == 180
elif x <= 0 or y <= 0 or z <= 0:
    print("Not a triangle; all angles must be positive")
# From now on, assume x, y, z > 0
elif x == y == z:
    print("Equilateral triangle")
# If three angles aren't all equal, any two might still be
elif x == y or x == z or y == z:
    print("Isoceles triangle")
else:  # Only case remaining: three distinct non-zero angles summing to 180
    print("Scalene triangle")
```

Whenever a check fails in an `if-elif-else` statement, you can assume its negation is true in subsequent checks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use elif. In your code when you give input 0, 0, 180 it match with the condition

```
if(sum!=180 or x<=0 or y<=0 or z<=0):
print('Not a Triangle')
```

and

```
if((sum==180 and x!=0 and y!=0 or z!=0) and (x==y or y==z or z==x)):
print('Isosceles Triangle')
```

When you use if condition after another if condition both will be checked whether first if condition is true or false.
for example:

```
a = 20
if a > = 15:
    print("condiiton 1")
if a >= 30:
    print("condition 2")
if a >= 5:
    print("condition 3")
```

Output:
condition 1
condition 3
Because 1st and 3rd condition are true. Even after the first condition was true, it checked 2nd condition and 3rd condition as well and found 3rd condition is also true.

```
a = 20
if a > = 15:
    print("10")
elif a >= 30:
    print("10")
elif a >= 5:
    print("5")
```

Output:
15

In the above case, the output will be the only condition 1 because after one condition true it will not check elif condition or else conditon.

Correct code will be:

```
angle1 = int(input("Enter 1st angle: "))
angle2 = int(input("Enter 2nd angle: "))
angle3 = int(input("Enter 3rd angle: "))

sum_of_angles = angle1 + angle2 + angle3
if sum_of_angles != 180 or angle1 == 0 or angle2 == 0 or angle3 == 0:
    print("Not A Triangle")
elif angle1 == angle2 and angle1 == angle3:
    print("Equilateral Triangle")
elif angle1 == angle2 or angle1 == angle3 or angle2 == angle3:
    if angle1 == 90 or angle2 == 90 or angle3 == 90:
        if angle1 == 45 or angle2 == 45 or angle3 == 45:
            print("Isosceles Right Triangle")
        else:
            print("Isosceles Triangle")
    else:
            print("Isosceles Triangle")
else:
    print("Scalene Triangle")
```